# Working with CSV file to send mail

Tags: linux, csv, mailx

I have a CSV file on a linux host, and it has 2 columns separated by commas:
1st column is email address and second column is corporate email address. The second column(corp email) could be one OR many corporate emails.

```
root@esm-pauth1 # cat owners_and_corps.csv`

kwolff@fordham.edu,osp
ayan@fordham.edu,fincenter
dyaun@fordham.edu,Cateringlc,RamHealth,fordhamfood
tyip@fordham.edu,Healthstudy,memoryhealth,psychidentity,sleepstudy,yddc
```

How do I use `awk`, `sed` or any command like that to send an email to the user to the users in the first column and notify them of the corporate email on the 2nd column (or possibly 2nd to nth column) depending on how man corporate emails the owner has. Keep in mind, the corporate emails in the file do NOT have `@fordham.edu` at the end of it

i.e) send mail to `ayan@fordham.edu` notifying her of corporate email `fincenter@fordham.edu`

i.e) send mail to `dyaun@fordham.edu` notifying him of corporate emails
`Cateringlc@fordham.edu`, `RamHealth@fordham.edu`, `fordhamfood@fordham.edu`

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting something along the lines of

`cat owners_corps.csv | awk -F, '{print "To: "$1;$1=""; print "Corp mails: "$0}'`

You mentioned the corp addresses will not have the @fordham.edu address but the one above does however I am not sure if that's just a formatting error.  You could use something like the following,

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
    #Get the email from the first column
    email_to=$(echo $line|cut -d, -f1)
    #Get the list of corp emails from the second column until end,   strip white space,  add @fordham.edu to the last entry (Won't have comma) then add @fordham.edu to all others 
    corp_emails=$(echo $line |cut -d, -f2-|sed 's/\s//g; s/$/@fordham.edu/g; s/,/@fordham.edu,/g')
    echo "To: $email_to :: list of corp addresses: $corp_emails"
    #echo "List of corp addresses $corp_emails" | mail -s "Corp Address List" $email_to
done < owners_corps.csv
```

To loop the file and add @fordham.edu to all the corp addresses.   It will echo what it would send by default but I included a sample email pipe commented out also if you where wanting to pipe directly to mail.